# Openshift origin 3.6 'Unable to mount volumes for pod "jenkins-1-deploy_jenkins...'

Tags: jenkins, openshift

After installing openshift origin 3.6 on centos 7 using the following...

```
yum update - y
yum install -y centos-release-openshift-origin 
yum install -y docker wget git net-tools bind-utils iptables-services bridge-utils bash-completion
yum install -y origin-clients

#edit /etc/sysconfig/docker file and add --insecure-registry 172.30.0.0/16 to the OPTIONS parameter.
sed -i '/OPTIONS=.*/c\OPTIONS="--selinux-enabled --insecure-registry 172.30.0.0/16"' /etc/sysconfig/docker

systemctl enable docker
systemctl start docker
systemctl is-active docker
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=8443/tcp
firewall-cmd --reload
systemctl restart firewalld

oc cluster up \
 --public-hostname 192.168.1.60 \
 --metrics \
 --logging \
 --host-data-dir /var/lib/origin/openshift.local.etcddata

echo 'export KUBECONFIG=/var/lib/origin/openshift.local.config/master/admin.kubeconfig' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export CURL_CA_BUNDLE=/var/lib/origin/openshift.local.config/master/ca.crt' >> ~/.bash_profile
sudo chmod +r /var/lib/origin/openshift.local.config/master/admin.kubeconfig

oc login https://192.168.1.60:8443 -u system:admin --config=/var/lib/origin/openshift.local.config/master/admin.kubeconfig
```

...i'm getting the following errors when trying to create a persistent jenkins from the provided template via the UI.

> Unable to mount volumes for pod
>   "jenkins-1-deploy_jenkins(bbbe1521-89c3-11e7-a10d-525400fd74ed)":
>   timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod
>   "jenkins"/"jenkins-1-deploy". list of unattached/unmounted
>   volumes=[deployer-token-5fxs8]

From a little more digging (not sure if its relevant)

```
[root@localhost ~]# grep -R 'Unable to mount volumes for pod' /var/lib/docker/

/var/lib/docker/containers/99a1249b1a3e3e5afced544cef97e35cb4be9a7d2436076cd7dc4cafa2d37854/99a1249b1a3e3e5afced544cef97e35cb4be9a7d2436076cd7dc4cafa2d37854-json.log:{"log":"E0825 18:29:34.020813   12557 kubelet.go:1554] Unable to mount volumes for pod \"persistent-volume-setup-mx76b_default(c3c1ec26-89c2-11e7-a10d-525400fd74ed)\": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod \"default\"/\"persistent-volume-setup-mx76b\". list of unattached/unmounted volumes=[pvdir pvinstaller-token-cc64d]; skipping pod\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2017-08-25T18:29:34.02126846Z"}
/var/lib/docker/containers/99a1249b1a3e3e5afced544cef97e35cb4be9a7d2436076cd7dc4cafa2d37854/99a1249b1a3e3e5afced544cef97e35cb4be9a7d2436076cd7dc4cafa2d37854-json.log:{"log":"E0825 18:29:41.993405   12557 kubelet.go:1554] Unable to mount volumes for pod \"docker-registry-1-deploy_default(c4a9a417-89c2-11e7-a10d-525400fd74ed)\": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod \"default\"/\"docker-registry-1-deploy\". list of unattached/unmounted volumes=[deployer-token-vwwtt]; skipping pod\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2017-08-25T18:29:41.993704804Z"}
/var/lib/docker/containers/99a1249b1a3e3e5afced544cef97e35cb4be9a7d2436076cd7dc4cafa2d37854/99a1249b1a3e3e5afced544cef97e35cb4be9a7d2436076cd7dc4cafa2d37854-json.log:{"log":"E0825 18:32:15.681098   12557 kubelet.go:1554] Unable to mount volumes for pod \"openshift-ansible-metrics-job-03486_openshift-infra(c77b9374-89c2-11e7-a10d-525400fd74ed)\": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod \"openshift-infra\"/\"openshift-ansible-metrics-job-03486\". list of unattached/unmounted volumes=[configdir inventoryfile openshift-ansible-token-s4mxx]; skipping pod\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2017-08-25T18:32:15.68182737Z"}
/var/lib/docker/containers/99a1249b1a3e3e5afced544cef97e35cb4be9a7d2436076cd7dc4cafa2d37854/99a1249b1a3e3e5afced544cef97e35cb4be9a7d2436076cd7dc4cafa2d37854-json.log:{"log":"E0825 18:32:15.781295   12557 kubelet.go:1554] Unable to mount volumes for pod \"openshift-ansible-logging-job-zls9w_logging(c92a40fa-89c2-11e7-a10d-525400fd74ed)\": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod \"logging\"/\"openshift-ansible-logging-job-zls9w\". list of unattached/unmounted volumes=[configdir inventoryfile openshift-ansible-token-wxb7l]; skipping pod\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2017-08-25T18:32:15.781854934Z"}
/var/lib/docker/containers/99a1249b1a3e3e5afced544cef97e35cb4be9a7d2436076cd7dc4cafa2d37854/99a1249b1a3e3e5afced544cef97e35cb4be9a7d2436076cd7dc4cafa2d37854-json.log:{"log":"E0825 18:32:18.946729   12557 kubelet.go:1554] Unable to mount volumes for pod \"jenkins-1-deploy_jenkins(1ee02f7e-89c3-11e7-a10d-525400fd74ed)\": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod \"jenkins\"/\"jenkins-1-deploy\". list of unattached/unmounted volumes=[deployer-token-fh2mb]; skipping pod\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2017-08-25T18:32:18.94764097Z"}
/var/lib/docker/containers/99a1249b1a3e3e5afced544cef97e35cb4be9a7d2436076cd7dc4cafa2d37854/99a1249b1a3e3e5afced544cef97e35cb4be9a7d2436076cd7dc4cafa2d37854-json.log:{"log":"E0825 18:41:51.284515   12557 kubelet.go:1554] Unable to mount volumes for pod \"jenkins-1-deploy_jenkins(bbbe1521-89c3-11e7-a10d-525400fd74ed)\": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod \"jenkins\"/\"jenkins-1-deploy\". list of unattached/unmounted volumes=[deployer-token-5fxs8]; skipping pod\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2017-08-25T18:41:51.284762329Z"}
```

per comment from "Graham Dumpleton"

```
    [root@localhost ~]# oc login https://192.168.76.60:8443 -u system:admin
Logged into "https://192.168.76.60:8443" as "system:admin" using existing credentials.

You have access to the following projects and can switch between them with 'oc project <projectname>':

    default
  * jenkins
    kube-public
    kube-system
    logging
    myproject
    openshift
    openshift-infra

Using project "jenkins".
[root@localhost ~]# oc whoami
system:admin
[root@localhost ~]# oc get pv
NAME      CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   RECLAIMPOLICY   STATUS      CLAIM             STORAGECLASS   REASON    AGE
pv0001    100Gi      RWO,ROX,RWX   Recycle         Available                                              19h
pv0002    100Gi      RWO,ROX,RWX   Recycle         Available                                              19h
pv0003    100Gi      RWO,ROX,RWX   Recycle         Available                                              19h
...
pv0068    100Gi      RWO,ROX,RWX   Recycle         Available                                              19h
pv0069    100Gi      RWO,ROX,RWX   Recycle         Bound       jenkins/jenkins                            19h
pv0070    100Gi      RWO,ROX,RWX   Recycle         Available                                              19h
pv0071    100Gi      RWO,ROX,RWX   Recycle         Available                                              19h
pv0072    100Gi      RWO,ROX,RWX   Recycle         Available                                              19h
pv0073    100Gi      RWO,ROX,RWX   Recycle         Available                                              19h
```

Comment: What do you get if you run ``oc get pv`` as an administrator? In other words, are any persistent volumes attached to the environment for claiming?

Comment: added to the summary

Comment: As I said, you need to run ``oc get pv`` as an 'administrator'. The error indicates you are logged in as 'developer'. Anyway, just realised you are using ``oc cluster up``, which means there should be PVs setup. You can verify by running ``oc get pv --as system:admin`` when using ``oc cluster up``.

Comment: ok, i apparently wasn't logging in properly, presumably due to the "--config" (which I think I tacked on while trying to troubleshoot another issue).  I'm able to login as admin now, and the summary has been updated with more useful results.  It looks look like there are plenty of pvs and jenkins is already bound to one of them?